# Jasmine .toHaveBeenCalledTimes throws 'undefined is not a constructor' error

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following unit test:

```
describe('shouldDeleteLogos', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      productService.product.project.parts['Logo'] = {
        name: 'Logo'
      };
      productService.product.project.parts['Accent'] = {
        name: 'Accent'
      };
    });

    it(`should only call deleteLogos once if the part was provided to the method`, () => {
      let part: Part = new Part();
      part.name = 'Logo';
      spyOn(creationSpacePSTLInstance, 'deleteLogos');
      creationSpacePSTLInstance.shouldDeleteLogos(part);
      expect(creationSpacePSTLInstance.deleteLogos).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```

However when I run the tests I get the following error: `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'expect(creationSpacePSTLInstance.deleteLogos).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)')`

What is wrong here? I've spied on the method and I want to test that it was only called one time. Based on the documentation this should be working. It does work with just `.toHaveBeenCalled();`, just not with the times argument.

Here is the versions of Jasmine and Karma that I'm using.

```
"jasmine-core": "2.3.4"
"karma": "0.13.22",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` was introduced in [Jasmine 2.4](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-21). If you upgrade, that should fix it.